# aol.com email headers

Tags: email

Does anyone know what these mean

```
x-aol-global-disposition: G
X-AOL-SCOLL-SCORE: 1:2:404915168:93952408
```

I see them in the headers of email received by aol.com they obviously put them there but I cannot find any information about what they mean.

any help much appreciated

Answer (score -2):

Read:

X-AOL-SCOLL-SCORE: http://aolanswers.com/questions/computers_internet_186539189821082

From what I can make out, they are added to emails which AOL believe to be spam.

Comment: Im I missing something there appears to be no answers on the link just pretty much the same question I asked?

Comment: Sorry, I may have copied the wrong link.

Answer (score -2):

I think it will either end in g or s depending on whether aol think it spam or not. Fear not however, I have received spam from both.

Comment: Can you cite some kind of source for this "thinking"?